# Free wiki-like webapp with internationalization, no ads, anyone can edit, mobile-friendly

Tags: gratis, web-apps, wiki

I am looking for a [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki)-like webapp for an open source software community.

Imperative requirements:

- Anyone can edit, no need to wait for approval by anyone. Registration is OK, but editors must be able to edit immediately afterwards.
- Viewable in all mobile web browsers.
- Free
- We don't have our own servers, so it needs to run "in the cloud"

Very desirable:

- Built-in internationalization (an article can have French, Japanese, Spanish version, with interlinks between each language).
- Editable in most popular mobile web browsers.

Bonus for:

- No ads.
- Either [Markdown syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) or the same syntax as Mediawiki.
- Fast.

Comment: With reference to this [meta post](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/675/are-hosting-recommendation-requests-on-topic) Hosting recs are off topic here.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Does that meta-discussion really apply for this question? OP is not asking for a hosting provider, but for a hosted wiki with specific features, i.e., a web app.

Comment: "Hosted wiki" Indicates a service req, which indicates a hosting req. Seems a classic case to me (otherwise I wouldn't have hit it with a closehammer), and I was discussing it on chat for a sanity check.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: I created a [meta-discussion about this question](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/836/60).

Answer (score 3):

[Wikia](http://www.wikia.com) is not perfect:

- Anyone can edit: OK
- Mobile view: OK
- Free: OK
- Internationalization: Need to ask Wikia admin to enable feature.
- **Mobile edit: KO** tried in Android Firefox for [sample](http://decks.wikia.com/wiki/Anki_APKG_format_documentation), did not work, empty text area.
- **No ads: KO**
- Syntax: OK
- Fast: OK

Comment: I don’t have a smartphone, but according to the [Mobile FAQ](http://community.wikia.com/wiki/Help:Mobile) "Can I edit content?", it should be possible within the mobile interface, but might require activation by the admin.

Comment: Wikia is full of ads. And, if you try to switch from Wikia to another host, Wikia may try dirty tricks, such as forking your wiki and maybe even making improvements to their fork. See ["Wikia#Advertising_and_use_of_free_content"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikia#Advertising_and_use_of_free_content>) on Wikipedia. You are better off choosing any MediaWiki hosting service _other_ than Wikia.

Comment: @unforgettableid: *any MediaWiki hosting service other than Wikia* <- Could you please add them as answers? Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: I'm not sure what's available. I've posted an answer telling you to avoid Wikia, and linking to a Google search saying which will show you what's available. I've marked the answer as "community wiki", so I don't think I'll gain any reputation from it. If you like it, please mark it as accepted, so that it will float to the top and fewer people will choose Wikia in the future.

Answer (score 1):

**I don't know, but avoid Wikia.**

Wikia is full of ads. And, if you try to switch from Wikia to another host, Wikia may try **dirty tricks**, such as forking your wiki and maybe even making improvements to their fork. See ["Wikia#Advertising_and_use_of_free_content"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikia#Advertising_and_use_of_free_content) on Wikipedia. You are probably better off  choosing any MediaWiki hosting service other than Wikia.

I'm not really familiar with the various options available. Do a Google search for [[ mediawiki hosting ]](http://www.google.com/search?q=mediawiki+hosting) and see what you find.